# Html5 video stops working when wrapping div is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the video to autoplay on page load. But when we create a wrapping div with jquery it stops working.

Html:

```
<div class="header">
    <video width="400" controls="" loop="" autoplay="">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
        <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg"></source>
    </video>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.header').wrapInner('<div id="site-wrapper"></div>');
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/91bn0g86/1/

Comment: I'm guessing it's because it starts autoplaying, then gets stopped automatically as it gets wrapped into the `#site-wrapper`

Comment: Heres an example of a video wrapped in a div http://jsfiddle.net/lsubirana/1Ly0f5cx/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it stops playing, but you can use following to re-trigger the autoplay. Note that autoplay won't work on mobile devices.

```
$('.header').wrapInner('<div id="site-wrapper"></div>');
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');
vid.play();
```

(and add id="myVideo" to your  element)